# Check document for types of questions and answers

Tags: c#

I am creating an application for my computing coursework where teachers upload a .txt file which contains questions for students and answers for each question.

In the file each question begins with a symbol to denote the question type (e.g. & denotes multiple choice), How should I check for the different questions?

I was thinking of using streamreader.readline() to read each line and then check position 0 of the string but is there a more effective way to do this?

Here is what the question document would look like just with more questions;

& Multiple choice question
~Correct Answer
-Incorrect Answer
-Incorrect Answer
-Incorrect Answer

? Textbox answer question
~Correct Answer

Comment: [String.StartsWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be more descriptive way of checking but it doesn't do magic internally.

Comment: File.ReadAllLines puills in all the file in one go and put it into an array. You still have the real task of checking all lines for their content type. So start with a complete list of cases!!

Comment: There is no 'ReadAllLines'?

Comment: Yes, there is. Check out this MSDN page. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Could you add a (small) example of such a txt file. Whether there is a more efficient way to do it depends on the actual format of the input.

Comment: Yeah just realised that's using file.... I was using streamreader

Comment: And just added an outline of the questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With such a basic layout, your only choice would be looping through all the lines in the document.

```
string[] documentText = File.ReadAllLines()

foreach(string line in documentText)
{
    // Skip empty lines
    if(line == string.Empty)
        continue;

    // Check the first character
    switch(line[0])
    {
        case '~': // Correct answer, skip
            break;
        case '-': // Wrong answer, skip
            break;
        case '&': // Multiple choice
            // Handle multiple choice here
            break;
        case '?': // Textbox queston
            // Handle textbox questions here
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using that method I would be unable to store the question and its answers  together

Comment: Where you handle the multiple choice questions and textbox questions, you can read and store the following lines until you encounter an empty line.